# Induction COQ Question

Tags: coq, induction

Just practicing some induction proofs and was wondering what would be the fastest and most effective way to solve this proof and proofs similar to this?

```
Lemma randompractice : forall n : nat,
    sum_n_random n * 30 + n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) * (3 * n * n + 3 * n).
Proof.
```

Answer (score 0):

The proof is a bit clumsy because you don't have proper
subtraction in nat. One way to go is to suppose first that `n` is not zero.

```ml
Lemma randompractice : forall n : nat,
    sum_n_random n * 30 + n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) = n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) * (3 * n * n + 3 * n).
Proof.
destruct n as [|n]; [trivial|].
assert (H : sum_n_random (S n) * 30 =
              S n * (S n + 1) * (2 * S n + 1) * (3 * S n * S n + 3 * n + 2));
    [|rewrite H; ring].
induction n as [|n IH]; [trivial|].
replace (sum_n_random (S (S n)) * 30) with 
             ((S (S n)) * (S (S n)) * (S (S n)) * (S (S n)) * 30 
               + sum_n_random (S n) * 30) by (simpl; ring).
rewrite IH; ring.
Qed.
```

Comment: you really did this! Impressive!!

Comment: Are you trying to get solution to some class exercises?

Comment: I think editing  a question to ask another question is not in the idea of stack exchange.....

Comment: Yep but you want other people to be able to keep track of what is going on.too....

Comment: Anyway if you are a beginner in Coq and you've managed to solve the inital question. Congrat!

Comment: ask it as a separate question and put back your initial question and you may get an answer ;-)